# PCB Layer Stack up for a 4-layer board

Tags: pcb

What's the best stack up for a four layer board with two power planes (plus and minus a dc voltage), a ground plane, and a signal plane? Can anyone share a resource that talks about the best practices for stack up and why they are the best practices? I can't find many things that address having two power planes. Is the following an acceptable stack up, or should the signal and ground planes be adjacent?

1. Signal
2. +VDC
3. -VDC
4. Ground

Comment: duplicate, asked a hundred times on this site already!

Comment: The stackup is meaningless without stating the spacing between layers. always try to have supply and return tightly spaced

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm struggling to find posts on here where they have 2 power planes like I do